# WildFly 11 admin console not resolving the variables

Tags: jboss, environment-variables, wildfly, wildfly-11, jboss-wildfly-11

I'm using the wildfly 11.0.0.Final and i'm loading the environment specific properties into standalone.xml via property file for data source

> ./standalone.sh -P /path/to/propertyfile.properties

My server starts without issue, when i test the data source it works.

But in my admin console the variable are not resolved. its still showing the variable names from standalone.xml but its picking the values from property files and test connection works good !! weird !!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you named the resource `${DS_TEST_POOL_NAME}` which can't use expressions. In CLI if you did something like the following:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=\${DS_TEST_POOL_NAME}:read-resource(resolve-expressions=true)
```

You'd see that `${DS_TEST_POOL_NAME}`, but your other expressions are resolved.